# Where to store data for Services

Tags: windows, service, storage

I'm looking at running a windows service, I can get that part running fine. the issue is where do I store the startup data. Things like server paths and user names, I was thinking the registry, however it is case insensitive. And to what I can gather currently the typical config file will not work. What and where is the best place to store this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows services can have App.config files just as any other exe can.

Comment: Thanks, Can I ask which folder the app config file must be installed to for the service to pick it up?

Comment: Same folder as the folder where the service is installed. The config file must be named with same name as the service exe.